# Counting substring characters in string

Tags: c, string, for-loop, if-statement

I'm writing a function that takes an input string consisting of a mix 'o' 'g' and 'c'. For each of these characters in the string, a certain symbol is printed. However, for the 'g' character, id like to count how many g's are in a row in the string. Here is the code I have so far:

```
void printSymbol(char *str) // takes
{
  int i; // counter for entire string
  int k; // counter for substring ('g' char)
  int count = 0; //stores amount of consecutive g's in substring

  for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) //looping until null term.
  {
    if (str[i] == 'o')
      printf("==========\n"); //symbol for o
    if (str[i] == 'c')
      printf(" ~~~~~~~~ \n"); //symbol for c
    if (str[i] == 'g') //if character is g
    {
      for(k = i; str[k] == 'g'; k++) //will loop through string starting at first g until next character is NOT g
      {
        count++; //count amount of consecutive g
      }
      printf("%d\n", count); //printing number of g's in a row
      if (count % 3 == 2) //All of these if statements are printing.
        printf("R==2\n");
      if (count % 3 == 1)
        printf("R == 1\n");
      if (count % 3 == 0)
        printf("R == 0\n");

      count = 0; // resets count for next set of consecutive g's in string
    }
  }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that it is printing all if statements in the for loop for the g char. If there are 3 g's in a row, it will print R = 0, then R = 2, and R = 1, because it will loop through each g and thus the remainder is changing. How do I stop this? Id like to record the remainder for the entire set of consecutive g's one time. So if there are 3 g's, Id like to print R = 0, and then reset the counter var.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not updating your `i` variable when checking for consecutive g characters. Your inner `for` loop that checks for consecutive g characters uses a separate loop variable, `k`, but since the `i` variable (the main loop counter) is not updated, then the string of consecutive g characters would be checked multiple times.

E.g.

Assume your string is "...ggg...". Then the first time you encounter this string, the inner `for` loop will check for the number of g characters and find that it is 3. It will then print out `R == 0`, reset the `count` to 0 and go back to the main `for` loop.

However, the outer `for` loop would then see the string as "gg..." and it will once again enter the inner `for` loop. This time, `count` would be 2 and `R == 2` would be printed out.

This process would then repeat for the final time. The string to be processed is "g...". This time, the `count` would be 1 and `R == 1` would get printed out.

To solve this, you simply have to update your `i` variable by adding the number of g characters you found - 1 (since the loop counter would increment at the end of the loop).